# How to display single Id from iTunes RSS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the code below to fetch iTunes charts directly from the RSS and display it. However, I only want to display the informations on the rss entry for one specific id. Any idea how this can be done?

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=200/xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var rank = 1;
            $(".loading").html("").hide();
            $(xml).find('entry').each(function() {
                var img = $(this).find("image[height=170]").first().text();
                var title = $(this).find('name').first().text().substring(0,35);
                var artist = $(this).find('artist').first().text().substring(0,30);
                var link = $(this).find('id').first().text();
                var m4a = $(this).find('link[title=Preview]').first().attr('href');
                var id = $(this).find('id').first().attr('im:id');
                var settings = {};
                var html = '<li class="' + id + '"><div class="artwork-wrapper"><audio class="player' + id + '" src="' + m4a + '"></audio><img src="' + img + '" class="artwork"></div><a href="' + link + '" target="_blank"><p class="title">' + rank +'. ' + title + '</p><p class="artist">' + artist + '</p></a></li>';
                $("ul.chartList").append($(html));
                $(".player"+id+"").player(settings);
                rank++;
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>

<ul class="chartList cf">
    <div class="loading"></div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you can just send the id in the query, so the url would be like this:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=1&id=1227088906/xml
```

Instead of:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/limit=200/xml
```

If I were you, I would maybe think about calling a page you are under control of and send `JSON` using `cURL` so that you can get back an array to process. Then you don't have to let your jQuery do all the work in processing the return data, because admittedly, what the iTunes API returns a bit of a mess!

**test.php:**

```
# Curl send the request to iTunes
function getAPI($url)
    {
        $con    =   curl_init();

        curl_setopt($con,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($con,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        $resp   =   curl_exec($con);
        curl_close($con);

        return json_decode($resp,true);
    }

if(!empty($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] == 'get_itunes_id') {
    $url    =   'https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topsongs/'.$_POST['url'];
    # Fetch array
    $array  =   getAPI($url);
    # Process the array using backend and then send back what you need in array/json form
    die(json_encode($array['feed']['entry']));
}
```

**index.php:**

```
<script>
$.ajax({
    url: '/test.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        "action":"get_itunes_id",
        // You need to come up with your mechanism to send or not send the id
        "url":"limit=1&id=1227088906/json"
    },
    success: function(response) {
        // Parse here and extract what you need from the array/object
        var getJson =   JSON.parse(response);
        // Do code
    }
});
</script>
```